# Child component not updating with updates state via Parent props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a parent component from where I am passing a callback function `handleProjectStagesSave` and some data as props to child component. In my child component, I am accessing the `props` and storing the `props` object as a whole to the state using `useState`.

**Parent component:**

```
function ProjectStages(props) {
    const [projectStages, setProjectStages] = React.useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
          ProjectAPI.getProjectStages().then((response) => {
            setProjectStages(response);
          });
    }, []);

    //this function is passed as prop to child component. child component send data through parameters back to parent
    function handleProjectStagesSave(val){     
      projectStages.someProperty = val;  //modifying state property here and updating the state below
      setProjectStages(projectStages);
    }

    if(projectStages === null){
      return (<Loader/>);
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {(() => {
           //loop through state data and pass props to child component
          return projectStages.phases.map((stage) => {
            return (
                <ProjectStageTile criterias={stage.criterias} stagesSave={handleProjectStagesSave}/>
            );
          });
        })()}
      </div>
    );
}
```

Now, the child component passes the callback function to it's own child component `CriteriaScores` which basically passes some data and sends it back all the way up to the parent.

**Child component:**

```
function ProjectStageTile(props){
    const [projectStageTileState, setProjectStageTileState] = React.useState(props);

    return projectStageTileState.criterias.map((criteria) => {

        return(
            <div>
                <div>
                    {criteria.selectedScore}
                </div>
                <CriteriaScores stagesSave={projectStageTileState.stagesSave} />
            </div>
        );
    });
}
```

It works fine and I get the data and store update the state `setProjectStages(projectStages);` in parent component. Now, I expect the child component to have the updated state data immediately. However, what I saw in React dev tools is that, after updating the state, I update the props in the child component manually, then the state changes are reflected in the Child component. Any idea what is wrong? Please let me know if I can clarify more on this.

**Update-1:**

Instead of mutating the state directly I tried something like below but got same result.

```
projectStages.phases.filter((phase) => (phase.gdfatStage === "bid"))[0].criterias
      .filter((criteria) => (criteria.criteriaId === val.split(' ')[1]))[0].selectedScore = val.split(' ')[2];
let newProjectStages = projectStages;
setProjectStages(newProjectStages);
```

**Update-2:**

Also tried below approach but it did not work.

```
let newProjectStages = projectStages;

newProjectStages.phases.filter((phase) => (phase.gdfatStage === "bid"))[0].criterias
.filter((criteria) => (criteria.criteriaId === val.split(' ')[1]))[0].selectedScore = val.split(' ')[2];

setProjectStages(newProjectStages);
```

Answer (score 3):

`projectStages` is a state variable, and you are mutating it directly.

```
projectStages.someProperty = val;
```

---

The recommended way of doing this is as follows:

```
setProjectStages(...projectStages, someProperty : val)
```

When you use `setProjectStages` react will re-render, and the most recent state variable will be passed to the child component.

Comment: Hi. Based on your answer, I have updated the question and added some more details. Please check.

Comment: @SouvikGhosh `filter` function returns variables, does not change the content of Array from which it was invoked. So, you need to use a temprorary variable to store the data that is returned from the `filter function`. Like this:  const tempVar = projectStages.phases.filter((phase) =>..... Then, use that variable to update the state like this: setProjectStages(...projectStages, phases: tempVar ).

Comment: This does not work. If you see, I am mutating the state property like this: `.......selectedScore = val.split(' ')[2];` and then storing the whole state object to a new temp variable `newProjectStages` and updating state: `setProjectStages(newProjectStages);
`.

Comment: Edited my question with some updates. Please check.

Comment: @SouvikGhosh Ok, I think you figured it out. As I said in my answer, mutating state was causing the bug.

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
const newProjectStages = Object.assign({}, projectStages); //this is important

newProjectStages.phases.filter((phase) => (phase.gdfatStage === "bid"))[0].criterias
.filter((criteria) => (criteria.criteriaId === val.split(' ')[1]))[0].selectedScore = val.split(' ')[2];

setProjectStages(newProjectStages);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer provided by @user9408899, I would add that the child component does not need to store its props in state. I would change it to:

```
function ProjectStageTile(props){
    const {criteria, stagesSave} = props;

    return criterias.map((criteria) => {
        return(
            <div>
                <div>
                    {criteria.selectedScore}
                </div>
                <CriteriaScores stagesSave={stagesSave} />
            </div>
        );
    });
}
```